# Urban Airship Landing Page not being dismissed

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

We have Urban Airship integrated in our app, and some pushes determine a landing page is displayed to the user when the app is opened.

This landing has a button that will usually trigger a deeplink, taking the user to a specific flow within the app.

The problem is that, when doing so, the landing page banner is NOT being dismissed. The deeplink works properly, but the banner is still shown above everything else, forcing the user to close it with the upper-right close button.

Any ideas on why this might be happening? Did somebody run into this issue? We are not doing anything on our end to handle this behaviour as I understand it should be automatic.

Thanks in advance for any tips you might throw our way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of the templates? There is a checkbox "close after action" that needs to be checked:

[image]

If you are using a custom template, call [UAirship.close()](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/custom-templates.html#uairship-close) after running the action.

Comment: I guess we are using the templates since we didn't configure anything on the app and it just started working. This checkbox is in the UA dashboard, right?

Comment: Added a screen shot. Its where you specify the action on the button.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to understand how is the whole Push Notifications handled, because I think it is being managed through an API or something like that.